# Strange insert bug

Tags: mysql

I have a very strange issue that I was wondering if someone could explain why it is occurring.

If I enter in the following statement, it hangs indefinitely:

```
UPDATE mturk_imdbentry SET rt_rating=%(rt_rating)s, rt_fresh=%(rt_fresh)s 
WHERE imdb_id=%(imdb_id)s''', data
```

However, if I use tic marks, it runs fine.

```
UPDATE `mturk_imdbentry` SET `rt_rating`=%(rt_rating)s, `rt_fresh`=%(rt_fresh)s 
WHERE `imdb_id`=%(imdb_id)s''', data
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but I would probably be looking at the MySQL log files to see any error that it might be reporting while it "hangs."